# my links aren't working (should be simple fix)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I've a problem with the links in the top right corner on this page (http://athemespage03.tumblr.com/). I've gone over everything in my code a million times trying to make sure it was all typed correctly, and it is. I can't seem to find out what's wrong. Help?

Here's my style sheet: (the problem is with the div id "squares")

```
body {
       background: url("https://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/wpYap0TYQ3mElk0kRbYn_LagunaHIke.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&s=d189029620c20323a937f5125a6ad96d")
       no-repeat center center fixed; /*CHANGE BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE*/
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
font-style:none;
font-family:calibri;
color:{color:text};
font-size:9px;
   }

   body, a, a:hover {
   cursor: url(http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/7673/cursorw.png), progress;
   }

    /*everything*/

    #everything {
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:100px;
    }

    /*--title--*/

    #title {
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
    font-size:80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 280px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:#fff; /*--CHANGE TITLE COLOR HERE--*/
    z-index: 1;
overflow: auto;
width: 98%; 
    }


#transbox {

position: fixed;
top: 150px;
right: 200px;
width: 600px;
height: 350px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000;
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); 
}

#transbox a:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

    /*--links--*/

    #squares {
    width:630px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:'calibri';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:250px;
    }

    #squares a {
    padding:3px;
    color:#000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    border: solid #000 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    #squares a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }


   #navigation a {
     font-family:'calibri';
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding:6px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

   }


 #navigation a:hover {
    background:#999;
    color:#fff;
    opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
```

and here's my actual html body:

```
<div id="everything">

<div id="title">navigation</div>

<div id="transbox">

    <div id="squares">
        <a href="/" title="home"></a>
        <a href="/ask" title="message"></a>
        <a href="http://tumblr.com/dashboard" title="dash"></a>
    </div>


<div id="navigation">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
            <td><a href="/">link</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

so yeah, I can't seem to figure it out. Please let me know if you need any other parts of my code to figure out what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The CSS property for the `#title` id, `width: 98%; ` is causing the issue. In case you haven't heard of it, Firebug is your friend in situations like this. Let's you inspect your CSS in the browser among many other useful features.

Comment: #title is on top of the links, even though it is "invisible", you need to either position it properly (:fixed is bad in this situation) or hack away at it by changing z-indexs, using pointer-events: none or something

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `#title` div, using `width: 98%;` and `z-index: 1;` is causing that, because when you try to hover `a` elemnts in the `#square` div, in reality you are hovering the `#title` div because it has 98% width and a `z-index: 1;` so it's covering the square div.

As you can see in the following screen shot:

[image]

Try to remove this two attributes from your title div CSS.

Answer (score -1):

The div title is above the square links!